# Pandas group by two columns and get top n rows of each value of one of the columns sorted in descending order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, greatest-n-per-group

I have a pandas dataframe with many columns (Two column names of interest are `a` and `b`)

1. I want to group by `a` and `b`
2. compute the occurences of each group
3. sort each group in descending order of occurrences
4. For each value of `b` I want to take top n values of `a`, which have most occurences.

I could do upto step 3, using the following code:

```
  a_b_count = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).size().reset_index().rename({0:'count'},axis='columns').sort_values('count', ascending = False)
```

But, for  each value of `b`, how to get top-n values of `a` for which occurrences are the highest?

**Example**

```
df =

     a           b       ...
     a1          b1      ...
     a2          b1      ...
     a1          b1      ...
     a1          b2      ...
     a2          b2      ...
     a2          b2      ...
```

Expected Output (for `n = 1`):

```
    a            b       count
    b1           a1        2
    b2           a2        2
```

Comment: Do you want the `count` or `Top N Values`? Those are two different. Your step 4 says Top N, but your output says count. Also, in your output, are columns a and b backwards?

Comment: I want the top n values on the basis of decreasing count. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) rather than a `sort`.  Will be faster for a smaller `n` relative to Series size.

---

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).size().groupby(
    level=1).nlargest(n).reset_index(-1, drop=True)
```

---

```
b   a 
b1  a1    2
b2  a2    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get a frequency of columns `a` and `b` :

```
pd.crosstab(df.a, df.b).stack().nlargest(1, keep="all").reset_index(name="count")
```